# Disable eager loading for single query in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

While working on optimizing some queries, I found some code that was loading a large amount of entities, grabbing their IDs, and dropping everything else. This is causing errors/long request times while Eloquent eagerly loads all the relations for these entities.

Since I know that in this case there is no use for the related objects, I want to temporarily disable eager loading.

Is there a way to disable eager loading on a query?

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent only eager loads when you tell it to (typically using the with() function while building the query). I had missed where someone elses code was adding all the relations in with